# How I can check if <tr> has no siblings at first and last when click

Tags: jquery, html-table, click

I am trying to check `<tr>` if its first or last element with jquery `prev()` and `next()` and I tried code like this, but this way didn't work what I expected. How I can check if `<tr>` has no siblings at first and last.
Any suggestion are welcome.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.myTable tr .btn').click(function(){
    if($(this).parent('tr').prev().length == 0){
      alert('noPrev');
    }
    else if($(this).parent('tr').next().length == 0){
      alert('noNext');
    }
    else{
      alert('hello');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <td>content a</td>
    <td>content b</td>
    <td>content c</td>
    <td><button class='btn'>click</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content a</td>
    <td>content b</td>
    <td>content c</td>
    <td><button class='btn'>click</button>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content a</td>
    <td>content b</td>
    <td>content c</td>
    <td><button class='btn'>click</button>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content a</td>
    <td>content b</td>
    <td>content c</td>
    <td><button class='btn'>click</button>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content a</td>
    <td>content b</td>
    <td>content c</td>
    <td><button class='btn'>click</button>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are looking for the first and last or the previous and next ? the question is a bit confusing in this. if first and last then look at my answer.

Comment: am looking for prev() and next(), but seems like I already know my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function (notice change of parent() to closest()) - parent() only traverses up the DOM once, to closest ancestor, closest() traverses up the DOM until it finds a first ancestor that matches your selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.myTable tr .btn').click(function(){
    if($(this).closest('tr').prev().length == 0){
      alert('noPrev');
    }
    else if($(this).closest('tr').next().length == 0){
      alert('noNext');
    }
    else{
      alert('hello');
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: I see, so when I use parent its only bound to <button> parent, which is <td>. I thought we can use parent() as long as we write DOM in parent(). Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @rnDesto, exactly. parent() only traverses one level up and should only be used when you're looking for a direct parent, not a "grandparent" or some other ancestor :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check with jQuery if an element is the first or last child like this:

```
$('.myTable tr .btn').on('click', function(){
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    if($tr.is(':first-child')){
      alert('first element');
    }
    else if($tr.is(':last-child')){
      alert('last element');
    }
    else{
      alert('somewhere in between');
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work as the $(this) is reference to button whereas OP wants to check for table row. So it would work if you changed $this = $(this).closest('tr')

Comment: @l.varga Yes, I saw it as soon as I posted the answer. Fixed it! Thanks for commenting on it though!

Comment: Yes, I see now :)

Comment: @dfsq Could you explain what you mean so I can improve the answer?

Comment: @dfsq Yeah I got that part, but what would you suggest to improve the code?

Comment: @Douwe de Haan : var  $tr = $(this).closest('tr');   
would do

Comment: @Douwe de Haan : for the explanation, every time you create a variable without using `var` it is the same as variable declared against the window element (global). it means memory is not cleaned up until you actually reload or get out of the page.

Comment: @js.palus I thought it was the other way around! I also checked [w3 schools JavaScript scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) which has some good examples! Thank you for the lesson!

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can use first() and last()

So that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.myTable tr .btn').click(function(){
    if($(this).parents('.myTable tr').first().length == 0){
      alert('this is the first');
    }
    else if($(this).parents('.myTable tr').last().length == 0){
      alert('this is the last');
    }
    else{
      alert('hello');
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Nope, won't work. You misunderstand what first and last methods do. Plus `$(this).parent('tr')` is wrong too.

Comment: Agree for the parent which doesn't bring the right set. though by having the right set of element first and last should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is work just use "parents('tr')" not parent('tr')

```
    $('.myTable tr .btn').click(function(){
      if($(this).parents('tr').prev().length == 0){
        alert('noPrev');
      }
      else if($(this).parents('tr').next().length == 0){
        alert('noNext');
      }
      else{
        alert('hello');
      }
    });
```